# CSS3 accordion list issue

Tags: html, css

Created one Css3 accordion but right now the output accordion default active content is last. I need default active accordion open content is first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the issue you are having is due to the fact that you add the following property to ALL of the input elements:

```
<input ... checked="checked" >
```

The result?

The browser reads the first one and sees, ok, checked, lets open it, but wait, nr 2 is checked as well, nr3 too...so it continues down the DOM until the last one specified as the checked one, which would be the lovely Selena Gomez...So it will open that one

The Solution:

Remove all the

```
checked="checked"
```

from the input tags **EXCEPT** for the first one, which you DO want to leave open..

See the new [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DKb3x/7/)